# Accounting formatting in Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

[image: Imgur]

```
x=pd.DataFrame([[5.75,7.32],[1000000,-2]])

def money(val):
    """
    Takes a value and returns properly formatted money
    """
    if val < 0:
        return "$({:>,.0f})".format(abs((val)))
    else:
        return "${:>,.0f}".format(abs(val))

x.style.format({0: lambda x: money(x),
                1: lambda x: money(x)
                })
```

I am trying to get currency to format in the pandas jupyter display with excel accounting formatting. Which would look like the below.

[image: Imgur]

I was most successful with the above code, but i also tried a myriad of css and html things, but i am not well versed in the languages so they didn't work really at all.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image, it makes it hard for people to cut & paste to replicate and test.

Comment: i posted code as text. i also included it as an image so that the output would be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output looks like you are using the `HTML` display in the Jupyter notebook, so you will need to set `pre` for the `white-space` style, because `HTML` collapses multiple whitespace, and use a `monospace` font, e.g.:

```
styles = {
    'font-family': 'monospace',
    'white-space': 'pre'
}

x_style = x.style.set_properties(**styles)
```

Now to format the float, a simple right justified with `$` could look like:

```
x_style.format('${:>10,.0f}')
```

[image: Float format]

This isn't quite right because you want to convert the negative number to `(2)`, and you can do this with nested formats, separating out the number formatting from justification so you can add `()` if negative, e.g.:

```
x_style.format(lambda f: '${:>10}'.format(('({:,.0f})' if f < 0 else '{:,.0f}').format(f)))
```

[image: Accounting Format]

Note: this is fragile in the sense it assumes `10` is sufficient width, vs. excel which dynamically left justifies `$` to the maximum width of all the values in that column.

An alternative way to do this would be to extend `string.StringFormatter` to implement the accounting format logic.

Comment: Thanks! i had kind of given up on getting an answer here! Thank you for the bit on getting the whitespace to repeat, i had made it work by using '&nbsp' but this is a particularly less janky solution! i am going to fully write up what i did and edit it in, but it will absolutely use that piece!